# How to Set Product attribute to 'Use Default' by SQL

Tags: product, attributes, sql, scope

I would like to set 'Name' and 'Description' attribute to Use Default for a couple of store views.

Like I have those store views.

- Eng CA
- Eng USA
- Fra
- Spa

So I would like to set globally for all products use the default for the first 2 store views.

I will accept as correct answer a SQL script that set one of the 2 attributes to Use Default for a Store view

Answer (score 3):

Attribute are defined in `eav_attribute` table.

On Magento 1.4 those has these ID:

- short Description -> 506
- Description -> 97
- Name -> 96

**Where data are stored**:

- Values for `NAME` attribute are stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.
- Values for `DESCRIPTION` attribute are stored in `catalog_product_entity_text` table.

**How it works**

- Magento creates a new row in the above tables for every scope (store) where I have deselect 'use default'
- Values for General Scope has 0 as `store_id`

So basically I neet to delete all values for attribute 96 and 97 that are related to the `Eng CA` and `Eng USA` storeview from `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

Suppose those store view has id 1 and 4

**SQL**

FOR `NAME` attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = 96 AND (`store_id` = 1 OR `store_id` = 4)
```

FOR `DESCRIPTION` attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE (`attribute_id` = 97 OR `attribute_id` = 506 ) AND (`store_id` = 1 OR `store_id` = 4)
```

:) if you want to remove them change 'SELECT *' with 'DELETE'